# Select another dropdown value based on the previous dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to html javascript and trying to learn it. I am having an issue that when I select a value of a dropdown it will select another dropdown value when certain criteria matches.
If they Select the option 4 (takeout) from service_type dropdown, the counter dropdown will automatically selected the option 2 driveway. else user are free to select any value on both dropdown. Only if they select Takeout, it will make driveway selected and also make the table service option inactive.
if they select 1,2 or 3 from the Service type dropdown then option 1 will be enabled.
I need a javascript and no jquery. Please help me

```
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <select name="service_type" id="service_type" class="form-control form-control-line" required>
            <option value="" selected="selected" >Select Service</option>
            <option value="1">Dining</option>
            <option value="2">Beverages</option>
            <option value="3">Liquor</option>
            <option value="4">Takeout</option>
        </select>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <select name="counter" id="counter" class="form-control form-control-line" required>
            <option value="" selected="selected" >Select Counter</option>
            <option value="1">Table Service</option>
            <option value="2">Driveway</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript like this:

```js
function Checker(el){

  const select = document.getElementById('counter');
  removeOptions(select);
  if(el.value == '4'){
    var option1 = document.createElement("option");
        option1.text = "Driveway";
        option1.value = "2";
        select.add(option1);
  }else{
    var option2 = document.createElement("option");
        option2.text = "Table Service";
        option2.value = "1";
        select.add(option2);
    var option1 = document.createElement("option");
        option1.text = "Driveway";
        option1.value = "2";
        select.add(option1);  

  }
}


function removeOptions(selectElement) {
                var i, L = selectElement.options.length - 1;
                for (i = L; i >= 0; i--) {
                    selectElement.remove(i);
                }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <select name="service_type" id="service_type" class="form-control form-control-line" onChange="Checker(this)" required>
            <option value="" selected="selected" >Select Service</option>
            <option value="1">Dining</option>
            <option value="2">Beverages</option>
            <option value="3">Liquor</option>
            <option value="4">Takeout</option>
        </select>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <select name="counter" id="counter" class="form-control form-control-line" required>
            <option value="" selected="selected" >Select Service Fist</option>

        </select>
    </div>
```

Create two function one for create option base to first choise and second for remove option everytime function is called.

Comment: please can you provide me an example

Comment: As you can see i posted snippet. run it

Comment: Thanks @Simone Rossaini for your solution. I really appreciate your time and effort. Thanks once again. You are a genius.

Comment: You are welcome, see next problem :) when you can upvote my answer please.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const firstSelect = document.querySelector('#serviceType');
const secondSelect = document.querySelector('#counter');

firstSelect.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if (event.target.value === '4') {
    secondSelect.value = '2';
    secondSelect.disabled = true;
  } else if (typeof event.target.value === 'string' && event.target.value.length > 0) {
    secondSelect.disabled = false;
    secondSelect.value = '1';
  } else {
    secondSelect.disabled = false;
    secondSelect.value = '';
  }
});
```

```html
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <select name="service_type" id="serviceType" class="form-control form-control-line" required>
            <option value="" selected="selected" >Select Service</option>
            <option value="1">Dining</option>
            <option value="2">Beverages</option>
            <option value="3">Liquor</option>
            <option value="4">Takeout</option>
        </select>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <select name="counter" id="counter" class="form-control form-control-line" required>
            <option value="" selected="selected" >Select Counter</option>
            <option value="1">Table Service</option>
            <option value="2">Driveway</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

**How does it work?**

You need to select your Select controls from DOM and then listen to `change` event on first select, then you can get value from it and depending on your choice change value of Select #2. In order to disable ability to choose another option in second dropdown, you can disable it.

Comment: _else user are free to select any value on both dropdown_  in your example in all case just one will be avaible. and second if you disabled select, post/get will not containe that value.

Comment: Another thing please stop use jsfiddle, when you can use internal tools `<>`  for create snippet

Comment: It's easy to disable/enable select from JavaScript.
Post/get with <Form />? Yeah, good point, though I don't see any Forms in author's post; if you post data via JavaScript, there shouldn't be any problems

Comment: Yes it is, but why not write a solution that works directly?

Comment: Updated my solution, thanks for pointing out to snippet.

I think it's matter of UX. I mean it would be kinda strange to let user know that select is enabled for choosing an option, but in fact there is only one option.
Also it's possible to disable options (not Select itself) instead of deleting them.